# Projector in Tensorflow v2 alpha

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to visualize some embeddings in Tensorflow r2 api, but there is no 
.contrib API.

Does somebody know where is the projector located?

> from tensorflow.contrib.tensorboard.plugins import projector
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'

Comment: [tensorboard from tensorflow-2.0](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/r2/get_started) there's been substantial api changes between tensorflow-v1 and tensorflow-v2. I saw the above link at the bottom of this issues discussion [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25356) that says the new documentation is with tf-2.0 in mind. My v2 is still compiling so nothing to tensorboard yet.

Answer (score 7):

You just need to import projector like this:

```
from tensorboard.plugins import projector
```

This works for me, so I hope it works for you

Comment: Could you please give a small example to show how to use it in TF2.0? Thank you.